# Optimal order fulfillment

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization

I have the following problem. A user has a cart with `N` items in it. There is a quantity `Q` of each item. Further, there are `P` warehouses, and each of them has a certain stock level for each product (which may be 0). Distances between each warehouse and customer are also known. I need to find a set of warehouses that can accommodate the orders and satisfies the following constraints (ordered by decreasing priority):

1. It should contain a minimal number of warehouses
2. All warehouses should be as close to customer as it possible.

Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPD:**

If one warehouse can't fulfill some line item completely, then it can be delivered by several different warehouses. E.g. we need 10 apples and we have 2 warehouses that have stock levels of 7 and 3. Then apples will be provided by these two warehouses (to provide 10 in total).

**UPD 2**
Number of available warehouses is nearly 15. So brute force won't help here.

Comment: You need to specify a bit more: what happens if a customer orders a quantity `Q` higher than the stock level `S` of some warehouse? Does another warehouse have to deliver all `Q` items, or can they share the order (i.e., the first warehouse sends `S` items, the other one `Q-S`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to go with David Eisenstat's solution. If you'd like to understand more about the topic or need to implement an algorithm for solving integer programs yourself, I can recommend the following reference:

[Chapter 9](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-09.pdf) from an MIT lecture on Applied Mathematical Programming gives a nice introduction into integer programming. On the third page, you find the **warehouse location problem** as an example of a problem solvable by integer programming. Note that the problem described there is slightly more general than the problem you described in your question: For your case, warehouses can be assumed to be always open (y<sub>i</sub> = 1), and the fixed operating cost f<sub>i</sub> of a warehouse is always f<sub>i</sub> = 0 in your case.

The rest of this chapter goes into the details of integer programming and also highlights various approaches to solve integer programs.

Comment: @blubb: Is there a implemented solution for this problem , that you know of as of now ?

Answer (score 10):

This is solvable by integer programming.

Let items be indexed by `i` and warehouses be indexed by `j`. Let `Qi` be the quantity of item `i` in the cart and `Sij` be the quantity of item `i` at warehouse `j` and `Dj` be the distance from the customer to the warehouse `j`.

First find the minimum warehouse count `k`. Let binary variable `xj` be `1` if and only if warehouse `j` is involved in the order. `k` is the value of this program.

```
minimize sum over j of xj
subject to
for all i, (sum over j of min(Sij, Qi) * xj) >= Qi
for all j, xj in {0, 1}
```

Second find the closest warehouses. I'm going to assume that we want to minimize the sum of the distances.

```
minimize sum over j of Dj * xj
subject to
for all i, (sum over j of min(Sij, Qi) * xj) >= Qi
(sum over j of xj) <= k
for all j, xj in {0, 1}
```

There are many different libraries to solve integer programs, some free/open source. They typically accept programs in a format similar to but more restricted than the one I've presented here. You'll have to write some code yourself to expand the sums and universal quantifiers ("for all").

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you could advice some article/tutorial/book for better understanding this topic?

Comment: I learned this material from a class that didn't use a textbook, sorry.

Comment: Integer programming is NP-hard. Any non-deterministic polynomial problem can be solved with it, but that doesn't help you since NP-hard problems don't (yet at least) have any efficient solution.

Comment: @Shahbaz Yes, I too have taken an algorithms class. Integer programming can be very effective as long as one avoids the kinds of gadgets that the NP-hardness reductions use.

Comment: @dandybreath It's come to my attention that Prof. Van Hentenryck is teaching a [version of 258 on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/optimization).

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not like this, but I have warehousing and order fulfillment processing experience. My personal real life experience didn't require an algo but a series of warehouse and customer service back tools (hopefully this will be food for thought to you and others struggling in the warehousing operations development world):

If you have 10 items on the order.

You have 9 in stock

You have 5 in one location and 4 in the other.

You split the order.  The 1 product that can't be fulfilled becomes a 'back order'.  It can be cancelled because you don't know when you or if your supplier is going to deliver. Make sure you hang on to your credit card authorization references.

The 9 left over (fulfill-able products) in stock will be queried against your warehousing virtual inventory for the best combinations.

In our case we do three things:

Can the fulfillment staff at a warehouse X transfer in the item from another warehouse easily? Yes/No

If so which products can transfer.

This might require human interaction based on warehouse load and capabilities.

If you are strictly going on automation and virtual inventory that fluctuates day in and day out, then you give it your best guess against warehouse inventories.

Next, split the order to two, with references to the main order for paper trails.

You then print to your destinations and hope they can fulfill, if they can't, then hopefully they can partially fulfill the order and generate back order that can be cancelled at the customer's request.

So basically here is what you have to code for.

Order
 First glance back order split and reference to main order.
 Inventory warehouse feeler function.
 Weighted split order based on virtual inventory with reference to main order based on warehouse capabilities to retrieve products from other warehouses.
 Print pick page (warehouse function)
 Back order or partial fulfillment manual functions (customer service tools)
 Collect the money on only the stuff you fulfilled when marked as shipped.

Considerations:
 Make sure the main order references the actions back order and splits.
 Make sure the splits and partial fulfillment orders references any additional back order and splits.
 Fullfill what you can
 Mark a shipped.
 Collect $$$ on the products that shipped.

Hope this helps and good luck!!!